# iptables + ipset: принцип работы

Tags: iptables, ddos, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот решил попробовать защитить свой сервер. Наткнулся на `ipset`. Нашел пример:

```
ipset -N blacklist iphash
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m set --set blacklist src -j DROP
```

Он работает, но вот что он делает я не понимаю, банит `ip`? Если да, то можно ли посмотреть список. Ну или как можно реализовать что бы если `iptables` нашел бота, то банился его ip.

Comment: Там такая же фигня..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может стоит попробовать совет: [Что нужно сделать, что бы ipset после reboot сервера сохранял сеты?](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/23489/).

Comment: По ссылке внизу как раз есть пример того как создать файл и записывать в него нужную инфу.